# Does a class with has-a relationship with a Collection object have a relationship with the Collection's elements?

Tags: java, composition, open-closed-principle

I am studying for the Java 8 Programmer II certification, and I'm going over the relationships classes can have. I understand composition, but I wondered if there is relationship considered between the elements of a collection that is a class variable of a class and that class. For instance, consider this code:

```
public class A {
    static ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();

    public A() {
        strings.add("foo");
    }
}
```

Do we say that the String elements of strings have a relationship with class A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all we should make clear if classes `A` and `String` would be in relationship if class `A` would have simple `String` field like so:

```
public class A {
    static String aString;

    public A() {
       aString = "foo";
    }
}
```

... I think so! And that would be "has-a" realtionship - `A` has-a `String`.

In your example there's a collection of `String`s. We can also say that class `A` has-a (lot of ;) `String`s... You can imagine that class `A` has a lot of relationships with `String` objects; class `A` aggregates them in collection. This is analogous to well known composition example *"car 'has' wheels"*.

You can also say that this is unidirectional one-to-many relationship (unidirectional because only one side of this relationship knows about the other).

Answer (score 1):

I would say yes.  The collection is almost immaterial here, more just an implementation detail of the "has-a" relationship between the class and the strings than anything else.  As for the fact that this is a class-wide relationship rather than a per-instance relationship, well, that's fine as long as you are aware and that is your intention.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is an ["aggregation"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition#Aggregation) or a composition depending on the lifetime of related objects. See also https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/61376/aggregation-vs-composition

Answer (score 0):

Has-a and is-a are intuitive concepts. They are not rules that compiler would check. It is a share vocabulary used to communicate to others effectively and used to make design decisions. So does class A "has" those strings? Yes, but you'll seldom state that rather you'd say Class A has a collection of Strings. A simple analogy is when you are carrying a bag, you wouldn't immediately say that you're carrying books, rather you're most likely to say you're carrying a bag full of books (collection of strings).

Comment: See. Depends on the context. Neither of us would be wrong.